# page source search engine

Tags: javascript, search, search-engine

Is there any search engine out there that would be able to search on the page source? e.g use something like "var myvar=1" as a search query, and it would return pages which have got this string in their source, e.g. in the script part.

Comment: Are you referring to something like [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch)?

Comment: @Shaz I was thinking that too, but I don't know how to make it actually do what the question asks, which is (I think) to search within `<script>` blocks and standalone .js files.